# regex pattern: split() vs find()

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm currently using this regex pattern = `"(?ius)[(?<=\\s)]\\bgo\\b(?=\\s)"`.

The purpose if to filter t-sql commands with the "go" as a delimiter.

Example t-sql code:

```
select * from table1 go
select * from table2
go select * from table3
```

**The pattern works with the `split()` method, but it does not work with the `find()` method.**

Example result with `split()` method:

```
select * from table1
select * from table2
select * from table3
```

Example result with `find()` method:

```
select * from table1 go
select * from table2
go select * from table3
```

It seams to have a problem when the "go" is at the end of the line or at the beginning. If the first "go" had a space after it, it works. I've already tried several things without any luck. In my case I really need to use the `find()` method, I can't just rely on split, because I need confirmation that the a "line" as a delimiter before doing the split.

Comment: I assumed you meant `matches()` instead of `matcher()`, but now I'm not sure that was right.  Can you show the actual code you're using?

Comment: I meant matcher(). See answer bellow and comment for example.

Comment: Okay, then I'll just remove that entirely.  The `matcher()` method just creates a Matcher object so you can call its `find()` method, so you don't need to mention it.

Comment: find() returns a boolean value to tell you whether there was any string or substring that matcher your regex. So your find() on that list should return true.

So can you please explain what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have found the solution

`(?iu)[(?=\\s)]\\b(Go)|(^go)|(go$)\\b(?!\\S)`

This pattern seams to negate the special characters without negating the start and end of line.

Answer (score 1):

I can’t reproduce your problem:

```
String pattern="(?ius)[(?<=\\s)]\\bgo\\b(?=\\s)";
String s="select * from table1 go\n" + 
        "select * from table2\n" + 
        "go select * from table3";
for(String sub: s.split(pattern))
{
  System.out.println("sub: "+sub);
}
System.out.println();

Pattern p=Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m=p.matcher(s);
int pos;
for(pos=0; m.find(); pos=m.end())
  System.out.println("sub: "+s.substring(pos, m.start()));
System.out.println("sub: "+s.substring(pos));
```

Will produce the same result for both ways. It would be very surprising to find a difference here, as the `String.split` method does the same thing internally.

Comment: In my code I deal with each line separately. There seems to be a problem with the end/beginning of the line. Try to run your code again but this time with the String: String s = "select * from table1 go\n" + "go select * from table2 go";

Comment: Your pattern says that there must be a space after `go` so if your string ends without any character after `go` the pattern does not match. The same applies when you double the word `go` and have only a single spacing character (line-feed) between them as it will be removed by the first match and therefore the second can’t find a space before the word. But there’s still no difference between `find` and `split`.

Answer (score 0):

To better clarify the problem above:

The problem doesn't seem to be with split() being different from matcher(), the problem is with the regex and the beginning and ending of the string.

My code treats each line separately so this was what fool me.

The regex "(?ius)[(?<=\s)]\bgo\b(?=\s)" is not catching the beginning "go" and ending "go".

**The idea is catching the "whole word", in this case the word is "go" so if the word is at the beginning of the string or at the end, i still want to include it.**

See example and comment above for clarification.

Still need to fix this problem, not having much success...